# Is there any way to execute msixpackagingtool.exe remotely

Tags: msix

I am running below code in powershell as administrator to package msi to msix using msixpackagingtool.exe using powershell.

Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotecomputerip -ScriptBlock { MsixPackagingTool.exe create-package --template C:\tortoisesvn.xml }

But I am getting this error:
Program 'MsixPackagingTool.exe' failed to run: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, I've never seen any docs on this. What is your use case?

However, other commercial tools that can build MSIX packages can connect remotely to a VM and perform the capture on that machine.

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/repackaging-VMs.html
- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/repackager.html

Tutorials: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/convert-legacy-installations.html

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer*